# Initialization Valgrind Error

Tags: c, data-structures, hash, initialization, valgrind

This function is part of a hash table. I am passing a hash-list to search through and a key.

```
int HashSearch (Hash_list h, char* key)
{
    struct ent *x = (struct ent *)malloc(10*sizeof(struct ent));
    for (x = h->table[hash(key, h->size)]; x!=0; x=x->next) {
        if (strcmp(x->pos, key)==0) {
            return x->num;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run it, valgrind keeps giving me the error

```
==1741== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1741==    at 0x4018DE: HashSearch (Hash.c:81)
==1741==    by 0x400FA7: function (Nine13.c:181)
==1741==    by 0x4009D8: main (Nine13.c:54)
==1741== 
==1743== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1743==    at 0x4018DE: HashSearch (Hash.c:81)
==1743==    by 0x400FA7: function (Nine13.c:181)
==1743==    by 0x4009D8: main (Nine13.c:54)
==1743==
```

(Line 81 is the line of code that starts with "for").

I feel like I've initialized both the `struct ent` and the hash list which is passed in. What's wrong?

Comment: split your for into sep. bits so you can see if its `h->table` or `x` that is giving you a problem, then work back.

Comment: You are allocating memory to `x` and then immediately reassigning `x` in the `for` loop so you are leaking memory.

Comment: My guess is that the problem actually lies outside of `HashSearch`. Is `key` definitely null-terminated? Are all entries in `h->table` initialized as well as their members (`pos`, `next`, and `num`)?

Comment: You have a few suspects for the read then: `key`, `h->size`, `h->table`, possibly `h` as well.  You've also got a leak as noted above.

Comment: ShafikYaghmour and jerry are both right.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem lay outside the function, and I've fixed the memory leak.

Comment: @user1710702 may I ask what exactly it ended up being?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `memset()` to clear the memory or use the function `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.

Comment: This is good advice in general, but x is immediately being reassigned, so that's not the cause of the Valgrind warning here (although it is a memory leak). Also, it's often better to use some other form of initialization with compound data types (`memset` and `calloc` both set all memory locations to the same value, which may not make sense for complex structures).

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098577/c-how-to-check-if-a-structure-is-initialized), it appears the problem was indeed that not all entries in `h->table` were initialized. Note that while using `calloc` or `memset` on `table` will solve the problem with a very high probability, it's technically not portable. While `0` is guaranteed to evaluate equal to null pointers, the bit pattern is not guaranteed to be all `0`s. Also, as pointed out in the other thread and my comment above, for complex data types you'll often want some other "empty" value.

Comment: This solved a similar problem of mine. I was not initializing the variables inside a hash table to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

From your response to our comments it looks like your problem is outside the function and that one of the items used within the function is not properly initialized. Outside of this your do have a memory leak, in this section of code:

```
struct ent *x = (struct ent *)malloc(10*sizeof(struct ent));
           ^^
  for (x = h->table[hash(key, h->size)]; x!=0; x=x->next) {
       ^^^^^
```

you are allocating memory to `x` and then immediately reassigning `x` in the `for` loop, probably this is what you meant to do:

```
struct ent *x ;
  for (x = h->table[hash(key, h->size)]; x!=0; x=x->next) {
```